# What crimes have been committed in English law?

Tags: england-and-wales, identity-theft

This is an odd question, I know, I’m writing a novel, know nothing about law, and would really appreciate your help.

Is this illegal (in England):

Person A looks a lot like Person B.

With Person B's consent, Person A pretends to be him. He lives his life, marries his girlfriend, lives with her, has sexual relations with her. But she doesn't know she's with Person A instead of the man she originally met, Person B.

Person A is also practicing law in place of Person B. The licence is in Person A's name, but Person B took the bar exam.

Would Person A go to jail for doing these things? What actual crimes has he committed?

*** For clarification: I understand this is a completely fictional scenario, so I'm not expecting, 'well, in the case of x versus y,' type answers. Just something plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At common law, which may no longer be the law in England, your name is what you and others use to refer to yourself.

So, even if person A was Christened "John Jacob Smith" at birth, while person B was Christened "James Bond" at birth, if person A lived his life as described using the name "James Bond", then "James Bond" would legally be one of Person A's names at common law.

But, even under that version of the law, doing something strictly as a consequence of impersonating someone else would usually be unlawful.

> He lives his life, marries his girlfriend, lives with her, has sexual
>   relations with her. But she doesn't know she's with Person A *instead
>   of the man she originally met, Person B.*

There is a concept of impersonating a spouse for sex that can constitute rape but I don't think that it applies in this case, because the relationship development for the most part with person A. Particularly importantly, the girlfriend is having sex with the person she married, even if she previously dated someone whom she has confused with her current spouse. Now, if person B returned and tried to have sex with the girlfriend by pretending to be person B's imposter, that might very well be rape.

This said, it is very hard to imagine the girlfriend really couldn't tell the difference between person A and person B, because generally speaking, intimate friends of even identical twins can tell them apart. So, this premise is wildly improbable.

> Person A is also practicing law in place of Person B. *The licence is
>   in Person A's name, but Person B took the bar exam.*

It sounds like Person A is practicing law without a license. This is definitely unlawful, although I don't know if it is actually a crime under English law as opposed, for example, to merely constituting a civil offense or contempt of court, or some form of civil fraud.

Comment: The Bar Council say "It is against the law for someone to (deliberately or wilfully) pretend to be a barrister when they are not", and I'll take their word for it; solicitors have similar rules. But here Person A actually has a licence, albeit fraudulently obtained: a fascinating point (*fascinating*, as Terry Pratchett points out, being lawyerspeak for "A hundred dollars a day and it'll take months").

Comment: @TimLymington Only a hundred?

Comment: @JAB I think he meant per 6 minutes - but it’s a quote from a book with a different economy.

Comment: ohwilleke You're an angel, thank you. I hadn't thought that he could be accused of rape. But the victim would have to bring charges of rape, and she wouldn't do that. Could a prosecutor bring charges of rape, even if the victim decided she didn't want to bring charges? Or could a prosecutor decide that he has committed too many infractions not to go to jail. Because otherwise it sounds like he hasn't done anything that he could be imprisoned for and I need him to go to jail for something.

Comment: @TimLymington Thanks!!! So, he's broken the law by pretending to be a barrister. Could he go to jail for that, or more likely just face a fine?

Comment: And, I'm aware the premise is implausible, it's taken a lot of research and a complex backstory to cover how he pulls this off.

Comment: ohwilleke I've been chatting to a friend in the Met Police and a trainee lawyer and they have both said the same thing, that he could be charged with rape. I'm going to post this as a separate question and see what people thing. I'd be grateful for any input if you have time!  Thx!!!

Comment: @GGx " You're an angel". Nope. I checked for wings just to be sure but definitely nope. ;)

Comment: @GGx I’m sure you would be right if your twin brother went to a date with your girlfriend and they had sex, with her thinking it’s you. In this case, it seems that this is a long term relationship and she agreed to have sex with the person she had sex with, even though she didn’t know his identity. Imagine you go from the USA to Australia, start s new life under a false name, find a girlfriend etc. No rape even though she doesn’t know your true identity.

Comment: In principle a judge would have to decide if consent was given. Imagine a man killed his wife, and many years later is released from jail. He starts a relationship, but his new girlfriend/ wife would never had entered the relationship if she had known he is a murderer. Is there consent?

Comment: @gnasher729 "his new girlfriend/ wife would never had entered the relationship if she had known he is a murderer. Is there consent?" Yes.